# Внешний ключ на праймари ключ таблицы самой на себя

Tags: sql, postgresql

```html
CREATE TABLE Tasks(
    "Title" VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
    "ParentTask" VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_tasks_parent_task FOREIGN KEY ("ParentTask") REFERENCES Tasks("Title")
);
```

Есть вот такая таблица. Есть ли возможность во второй столбец вставлять одинаковые значения из 1го?

| Task | ParentTask |
| --- | --- |
| First | null |
| Second | First |
| Third | Second |
| Forth | Second |

Нужно вставить в неё вот такие данные. Но из-за попытки 2 раза во 2й столбец вставить "Second" вылетает ошибка 'Key is not present in table'

Comment: Внешний ключ может повторяться конечно, если на него ограничение уникальности не наложено.

Comment: Не понятно, в чем у Вас проблема (если речь о postgresql). Ограничения, о котором Вы пишете, не видно в определении таблицы. Сообщение об ошибке ``Key is not present in table`` говорит, что нужного ключа (еще) нет в таблице, чтобы вставлять подчиненные записи. Т.е. надо сперва добавить запись ``(Second,First)`` потом вставить ``(Third,Second)`` и ``(Forth,Second)``  На вопрос 0 ответ ДА.

Answer (score 2):

Либо вставлять данные строго в порядке корректности связей:

```
insert into tasks values ('First', null);
insert into tasks values ('Second', 'First');
insert into tasks values ('Third','Second'), ('Forth','Second');
```

либо изменить constraint на [`DEFERRABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html)

```
CREATE TABLE Tasks(
    "Title" VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
    "ParentTask" VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_tasks_parent_task FOREIGN KEY ("ParentTask") REFERENCES Tasks("Title") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
);
begin;
set constraints fk_tasks_parent_task DEFERRED;
insert into tasks values ('First', null), ('Second', 'First'), ('Third','Second'), ('Forth','Second');
commit;
```

Если ограничение объявить как `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` - то отдельная команда `set constraints` будет не нужна и проверка будет по-умолчанию откладываться на время `commit`.

Неудобный момент в том, что при отложенной проверке ограничений будет дольше выполнятся сам commit, а не непосредственно модифицирующие данные запросы. Если, например, заметили в логах, что commit выполнялся 200мс - то будет мало понятно, почему и какие ограничения он перепроверял.